# Mirror mode openldap perfromance is slow when either mirrored node fails

Tags: rhel, ldap, openldap

I'm managing two openldap servers in mirrored mode. When either server fails ldap performs poorly, 30 seconds to several minutes to authenticate. Affected services include ssh and X11 (XDMCP). A mirrored dns also runs on both servers.

Running openldap 2.4.23-32 on RHEL 6.3.

Comment: show us your configuration please

Comment: Found it... it was an obscure DNS issue.